# How to make a difficult GROUP query for getting information by 2 groups

Tags: sql

There is the following table:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
```

Maker - maker of device, type is PC, Laptop, Printer, model is primary key. I need to get all makers which makes devices with the same type only and makes more than 1 model. Information for showing is maker, type. I've got the following query:

```
SELECT maker, type, count(*) as how_many 
FROM Product 
GROUP BY maker, type 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

But I don't know how to get makers with the same type of devices.

UPDATE: for, example, there are the following records:

```
A - 01 - Printer
A - 02 - PC
A - 03 - Laptop
B - 04 - Printer
B - 05 - Printer
```

B is good maker, because all his devices has got the same type - 'Printer'. Have I fixed you?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  "makes with the same type of devices" is not clear to me.  The same type as what?

Comment: If you're grouping by maker and type, you will get a record for each maker/type compbination where they make more than one model.  What do you mean by "but I don't know how to get makers with the same type of devices" ?

Comment: Please, look at update. Maker 'A' is not needed maker, because he has got devices with the different type. I need to get only 'B' maker, because all his devices has got 'Printer' type.

Comment: Could you please edit again and include what your desired output is?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you the result that you want:

```
select maker, type, count(*) how_many
from product p1
group by maker, type
having how_many = (select count(type)
                   from product p2
                   where p1.maker = p2.maker
                   group by maker)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d14f2/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple aggregation query with a `having`clause:

```
select maker
from product
group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 1 and count(distinct type) > 1
```